# How to deploy multi container application to heroku via travis ci

Tags: docker, heroku, containers, travis-ci

Hey I am using travis ci and i dont understand what i have to write inside the travis yml to deploy multi container into heroku
this is my travis.yml

```
sudo: required
services:
  - docker

before_install:
  - docker build -t 307949230/client-test -f ./client/Dockerfile.dev ./client

script:
  - docker run 307949230/client-test npm test -- --coverage

after_success:
  - docker build -t 307949230/mern-client ./client
  - docker build -t 307949230/mern-nginx ./nginx
  - docker build -t 307949230/mern-server ./server
  # Log in to the docker CLI
  - echo "$DOCKER_PASSWORD" | docker login -u "$DOCKER_ID" --password-stdin
  # Take those images and push them to docker hub
  - docker push 307949230/mern-client
  - docker push 307949230/mern-nginx
  - docker push 307949230/mern-server
```

Comment: Hey, have you found a solution to this?

Comment: I'm still trying to figure it out too but I think you can use the heroku cli instead. Such as `heroku container:push web && heroku container:release web`. And the `container:*` commands have flags you can use to specify sub directories which contain a Dockerfile.